# Suppose $ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, and that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers both less than $n$. Does it follow that either $a | n$ or $b | n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose $ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, and that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers both less than $n$. Does it follow that either $a | n$ or $b | n$? If it does follow, give a proof. If it doesn’t, then give an example.

I can't possibly think of an example for this, but unsure about any possible proof otherwise.

Comment: `ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}` . Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: consider $n = 4$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I feel like I'm making a mistake, but don't know what.

Comment: But $a$ and $b$ are positive integers less than $n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A counterexample would be $a=6$, $b=6$, and $n=9$.

Now $0<a,b< n$ and $ab=36=4\cdot 9\equiv 0\pmod 9$, but $a\nmid n$ and $b\nmid n$.

Answer (score 2):

No. $a=12, b=20, n=30...$ Or $a=p^2 q,\; b=p^2r, \;n=pqr $  with $p,q,r$    primes with $p<q<r.$